# Não consigo esconder um elemento com css pegando pelo attributo data-column

Tags: css, jquery, html

Tenho um input com o código abaixo:

```html
<input type="search" class="filtro tablesorter-filter" placeholder="" data-column="1">
```

Estou usando na página um css para tentar esconde-lo:

```html
<style> input[data-column=1] { display:none } </style>
```

Mas o elemento continua sendo mostrado na tela.

Quando coloco assim funciona normalmente, porém há mais de um e o filtro único seria apenas o data-column:

```html
<style> input[type=search] { display:none } </style>
```

Estou fazendo algo de errado? Esse atributo por não ser padrão do html não é mapeado pelo CSS?

**OBS:** Tentei usar esse `seletor { input[data-column=1] }` com o JQuery, mas também não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você tem que colocar o valor do atributo entre aspas, dessa forma:

```html
<style> input[data-column="1"] { display: none } </style>
```

Porém este tipo de seletor não funciona no IE8, você pode fazer isso via jQuery:

```js
$('input[data-column="1"]').css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: O jQuery é bonzinho e te deixa omitir as aspas, mas o CSS, não.

Comment: Que estranho, eu jurava que era sem aspas. Quando tento colocar input[type=search] sem aspas funciona. Porque data-column nao funciona?

Comment: digamos que search não é um valor, é uma propriedade...não sei se é bem isso, com essas palavras...

Comment: os elementos data- são como se fossem variáveis, o conteúdo que tem é um string, e tem que ser comparado assim. o type do input por causa da história com HTML4 e anterior tem definição de dar o mesmo com ou sem aspas, porém os elementos data- ainda não existiam antes...